# Excel Macro For Loop Printing

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble creating a very basic macro that prints out a value down a column.

The values are generated by the function: 
f(x) = Exp (-x) * sin(x), where x = 0 through 9 in a for loop.

Current code:

```
Function calculateFunction()
  MaxNumber = 9
  rowNumber = 1
    For i = 0 To MaxNumber
      Cells(rowNumber, 1) = Exp(-i) * Sin(i)
      rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next
End Function
```

The code is put in "Module 1" and run with the text:

```
=calculateFunction()
```

In a cell. The only cell that populates is cell (1,1) which says "0.00"  There is no error.

Comment: `Function` is meant to return you something. `Sub` is a procedure to do things for you. What you are doing falls into a Sub.

Comment: Your function calculate result as function of cells(rcNumber,1), Thus when it place in cell(1,1) and value of cell(1,1) is 0 result was 0. That result place in cells(1,1). If you need function calculates f(x) you must save x in one colunm, then place function in another colunm in that function you refer on colunm contain value x. That is not in same cells x and F(X), how you write in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sub` instead of `Function` in order to change other cells. You can't call a function from formula textbox (=...) that alters other cells. Of course functions can make changes to cells but not when called by a cell. Here you don't need a method that returns something.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be more logical to change your function to:

```
Function EXPSIN(i As Long) As Double
    EXPSIN = Exp(-i) * Sin(i)
End Function
```

And then populate your target cells using the formula:

```
=EXPSIN(ROW()-1)
```